# Python: Get index of last element that is smaller than a given number

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have the following numpy array of time points of a certain measurement, where it can be assumed that it is ordered from small to large:

```
time_points = np.array([0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6])
```

I would like to find the **index** of the last element that is lower or equal to three. In this example the element is `2.8` and the index is `5`. So I would like a python code that gives me that `5`. A relatively short code can do this:

```
index = 0
while time_points[index] <= 3:
    index += 1
index -= 1
```

But my `time_points` array can get very long and I was wondering if there is a faster way, just like the method `index()` to do this in only one line? Something like

```
>>> time_points = np.array([0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6])
>>> index = function(time_points, 3)
5
```

Or perhaps code with multiple lines, but that uses the `numpy` library to make the operation faster.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is O(n) - that means its computation time depends on your length. That's  the fastest way to get through whole list. Since your list is ordered, you can try bisection method - that is check middle element to see on which side your result will be, then check middle of that part... until it finds the element. This mean that for sorted stuff, you can check less than whole list, even in most pessimistic case - it's O(log n)

Comment: As for how... there is already a function - or rather several functions - for it in python https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html Because you don't want to insert stuff, you might need to +-1 to your search result to get the index of existing element, instead of one after it

Comment: @h4z3. Thanks you for the answer! I was experimenting a bit with the functions (also just for fun) and I learned new stuff. Nonetheless, I think I'm gonna go with the answer of Karun Ellango. But again: thank you for helping.

Comment: No problem. I don't deal with numpy myself, so I just suggested a general solution, not numpy-specific one - that's why it was a comment, not an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[numpy.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is literally the exact function you need.

It uses binary search to find the closest point, where it "cuts" the list in half everytime and only looks at that half.

It can be used like this, say arr is the list.

```
>>> arr = np.array([0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 2.0, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6])
>>> arr.searchsorted(3, 'right') - 1
5
>>> arr.searchsorted(2.8, 'right') - 1 
5 
>>> arr.searchsorted(0, 'right') - 1 # No greater item
-1
```

I doubt there is a faster numpy method as this is a one liner, and uses binary search which is generally the fastest search method on a sorted array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I upvoted it, but my reputation is not high enough. I marked it as the solution, because I have the feeling it is indeed the best option.